# Add User related objects in User model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a Django 1.10 project, in which I have a model called TaggedArticle which is related to a user with the related_name as "tagging", now I want to display a table of TaggedArticle objects when we open a user object in Django admin.How can I achieve that functionality in Django Admin?

Here are my models:
**TaggedArticle:**

```
class TaggedArticle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tagging')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)
    category_fit = models.CharField(choices=choices, max_length=255)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='articles')
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255,)
    relevant_feedback = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
```

> **Update: admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import TaggedArticle as Tagged
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import TaggedArticle
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
admin.site.unregister(User)

class InlineTaggedArticle(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TaggedArticle

class CustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'date_joined'
    inlines = [InlineTaggedArticle, ]
    list_display = list(UserAdmin.list_display) + ['totol_tagged_article']

    def totol_tagged_article(self, obj):
        return obj.tagging.all().count()

admin.site.register(User, CustomAdmin)


class TaggedArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'created_at'
    fields = ['category_fit', 'article', 'link', 'relevant_feedback', 'category', 'user', 'email']
    list_display = ['article', 'link', 'user', 'email', 'relevant_feedback']
    list_filter = ['user', 'email']
    model = Tagged


admin.site.register(Tagged, TaggedArticleAdmin)
```

> **Update:** Here are the screenshots:

1. **TaggedArticle List View:**

[image]

2. Detail Page for TaggedArticle:

[image]

3. Detail page for User:

[image]

On user's detail page, all fields from TaggedArticle object should be displayed.
Help me, please!
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import TaggedArticle
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User =  get_user_model()
admin.site.unregister(User)

class InlineTaggedArticle(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TaggedArticle


class CustomAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [InlineTaggedArticle,]
    list_display = list(UserAdmin.list_display) + ['totol_tagged_article']

    def totol_tagged_article(self, obj):
        return obj.tagging.all().count()
admin.site.register(User, CustomAdmin)
```

Now you will see `TaggedArticle` table in User detail page in Django admin

Comment: Hi, @NeErAj! Also, how can I display the total number of tagged articles in user detail page?

Comment: Above code will show all tagged article in user detail page in django admin.
did you try above code?

Comment: yup, it's working! but now I need to display the total count of tagged articles also!

Comment: You can't show count in detail page but can show in list page of user.
check my updated code

Comment: Hi @NeErAj! what do mean by in list page of user? it doesn't change anything is user detail page!

Comment: Above code will not change in detail page but do you know where list_display we used in django? user list page means > which page of django that show all users in your db.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_images/list_filter.png this is user list page there you will see extra column of total when you use above code

Comment: Hi, @NeErAj ! when I deployed my Django site now on production it displays only two fields ( category_fit & article) in Django admin, why other fields are not displaying in Django admin on production?  help me, please!

Comment: what is Tagged or TaggedArticle? both are different models?

Comment: A same model, also imported as Tagged!

Comment: Only displaying 2 fields category_fit & article other fiedls like user, email,link,category & relevant_feedback are displaying in list view page django admin.

Comment: Hi @NeErAj! have you find any solution, please!

Comment: Now, all fields are displaying inside detail view of TaggedArticle in django admin, but still not display all fields inside User's detail page as we are displaying TaggedArticles for that user in table form.

Comment: I checked above code of you but there is no issue. I think something is different in your production code

Comment: I have pushed my code to github then cloned it from my repository on production, the only difference is db backend at local env I'm using sqlite but at production i'm using postgresql, even i have tried sqlite also on production it doesn't make any change.

Comment: add screenshot what issue getting regarding field showing in admin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157229/discussion-between-abdul-rehman-and-neeraj-kumar).

Comment: I have added screenshots!

Comment: this is very strange issue. can you check with `admin.StackedInline` replace with `admin.TabularInline`

Comment: It doesn't make any changes regarding fields!

Comment: Hi @NeErAj! I have seen a `Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.` in browser's console when I inspect element for these fields, also I have seen Worker Timeout for the gunicorn process, it's may a network OR gunicorn issue?

Comment: yeah. Network issue may be server error that not showing others fields

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import TaggedArticle
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['']
admin.site.register(TaggedArticle,TaggedArticleAdmin)
```